# How can I 'push_back' large size objects in STL containers?

Tags: c++, exception, stl, containers

I'm trying to 'push_back' large sized objects into STL container(deque). But I can't 'push_back' objects that uses large memory.

Try-catch block gets the std::length_error exception.

How to store the large sized and complicated objects in STL containers ?

```
typedef std::deque <
    LargeData,
    boost::pool_allocator <
    LargeData
    , boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete
    , boost::details::pool::default_mutex
    , 32
    , 0
    >
> LargeDataDeque;

LargeDataDeque v;
LargeData d;
try
{ 
    v.push_back(d); 
}
catch( std::length_error &e )
{
    cout << e.what();// this line outputs 'too long'
}

//LargeData body
struct LargeData
{
std::wstring name;
CRect desktop_rect;

// computer vision attributes
bool is_cv_target;
bool is_vm_master;
bool is_face_detect_target;
bool is_facemask;
FaceMaskPart facemask_part;
std::deque<std::wstring> masters;
std::deque<std::wstring> slaves;
CPoint facetrack_com;
//

CImage image;
CPoint com;
Vec2 curr_coord_ratio; // %
Vec2 prev_coord_ratio; // %
Vec2 prev_size_ratio;
//CPoint translation;
Vec2 translation;
CPoint trans_diff;
double scale;
double scale_diff;
double degree;
CRect region;
CartesianRect rot_region;
CRect initial_region;
CartesianRect initial_rot_region;

CRect orig_bmp_region; // special tmp data for bmp-wipes
int cap_number;
std::wstring id;
CRect tmp_region;
int depth;
int alpha;

// cv
IplImage *effect_frame;
IplImage *effect_tmp_frame;
IplImage *gray_frame;
IplImage *sepia_frame;

bool use_brightness;
double brightness;
bool use_contrast;
double contrast;
bool use_blur;
int blur_intensity;

bool blur_face;
cv::Mat ft_frame, smallImg;
cv::CascadeClassifier cascade_face_cpu;
std::deque<FaceTrackRegions> facetrack_regions;

bool flip_vertical;
bool flip_horizontal;
bool flip_hv;
bool use_negaposi;
bool use_sepia;

CvMat *cvm_clusters;
CvMat *cvm_points;
CvMat *cvm_color;// = cvCreateMat (MAX_CLUSTERS, 1, CV_32FC3);
CvMat *cvm_count;// = cvCreateMat (MAX_CLUSTERS, 1, CV_32SC1);
CvMat *cvm_centers;// = cvCreateMat (MAX_CLUSTERS, 1, CV_32SC1);

bool use_erode;
bool use_dilate;
int erode_iteration;
int dilate_iteration;

bool use_threshold;
int min_threshold;
int max_threshold;
int threshold_type;
// cv

std::deque<WipeEffect> effects;

bool selected;
bool activated;
bool visible;

WipeSourceType type;
WipeAlignment alignment;

int imagesource_index;
CString image_path;
FIBITMAP* fib_image;
double image_ratio;
bool use_alpha_blend;
bool use_chromakey;

// WS_Bitmap specific
CPoint last_diff_from_ecom;

// Direct2D
// captured bitmap
D2D1_SIZE_U d2dcapbitmap_size;
unsigned int d2dbitmap_bytes;
unsigned int d2dbitmap_pitch;
CComQIPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> d2dcapimage;

LPVOID *d2dtmpbits;
boost::shared_ptr<BYTE> d2dcapbits;
HBITMAP hbm_d2dtmpbits;
HBITMAP hbm_d2dtmpbits_old;
HDC hdc_d2dtmpbits;
BITMAPINFO bi_d2dtmpbits;

// CaptureWorker thread stuffs
boost::shared_ptr<CaptureWorker> capture_worker;
boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> capture_worker_thread;
//boost::mutex capture_mutex;

// static bitmap
D2D1_SIZE_U d2dstaticbitmap_size;
BITMAPINFO bi_d2dtmpbmpbits;

BYTE *d2dorigbmpbits;
HDC hdc_d2dorigbmpbits;
HBITMAP hbm_d2dorigbmpbits;

// static bitmap's working resources
BYTE *d2dworkbmpbits;
HDC hdc_d2dworkbmpbits;
HBITMAP hbm_d2dworkbmpbits;
CComQIPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> d2dbitmap;

/*CamImageGrabber camgrabber;
CSize prev_cam_reso;*/
CamDeviceInfo caminfo;


// Video frame stuffs
boost::shared_ptr<Video> vid;
bool vid_ready;
bool vid_loop;
bool vid_use_slomo;
boost::shared_ptr<BYTE> vid_buff;
}
```

Comment: `deque::push_back` doesn't throw `length_error`. Are you sure the error is not being thrown by `LargeData`'s copy constructor? You should make the class move constructible and use `v.push_back(std::move(d));`

Comment: also consider using `emplace_back`

Comment: I tried emplace_back and definitely using deque<T>. But length_error has been thrown. And what() returns 'vector<T> too long'. Is it correct behavior ? I'm using VC++2013, boost1.55, Windows8.1 64bit.

Comment: I have 'Unhandled exception at 0x76991D4D in myapp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location 0x0099DCC0.' on boost::pool_allocator::construct.

Comment: Please put all relevant information in your question body.

Comment: I've added a description of LargeData. Please refer it.

Comment: what is the type of `v` in the `try-catch` block? Does it also have a non-standard allocator?

Comment: sorry. I mended wrong code.

Comment: ＠Praetorian Thanks, Praetorian. But std::move didn't work well.

Comment: I've decided to use pool-pointer method to avoid this problem and my application working well. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

`std::deque::push_back` shouldn't throw `std::length_error` unless you have billions of elements in the deque. (In which case there is probably not enough memory to hold all the elements anyway, and it's got nothing to do with the deque itself.)

If you're actually using too much memory, you get `std::bad_alloc` (at least, if you are using the default allocator).

Since this isn't the case, my guess is that you have undefined behaviour somewhere in your code, that is resulting in the deque's internal memory being corrupted somehow.

Comment: I'm using working code in VC++2010, boost1.46 and Windows7 64bit. But it doesn't work on VC++2013, boost1.55 and Windows8.1 64bit.

Comment: @user3840701 You could still have a bug in your code. Undefined behaviour means it *might* work, and it might not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm checking.

Comment: I have 'Unhandled exception at 0x76991D4D in myapp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location 0x0099DCC0.' on boost::pool_allocator::construct.

Comment: @tensor01 If the allocator throws then it means you ran out of memory. Although actually I'm not sure what is going on now, since boost::pool_allocator isn't supposed to throw std::length_error as far as I know. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/pool/doc/interfaces/pool_alloc.html

Comment: Oh, it's a very strange case. I definitely using std::deque with boost::pool_allocator and it throws std::length_error... hmmm.

Comment: I've 0.9GB of free memory when I debugging.

Comment: I've decided to use pool-pointer method to avoid this problem and my application working well. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

With C++11 you can make your large object non-copyable and then emplace the object into a container, or move it into, instead of inserting a copy of the object.

Comment: Oh, that's a horrible thing.I can 'push_back' when I allocate large array by 'new'.

Comment: I've decided to use pool-pointer method to avoid this problem and my application working well. Thanks all.

Answer (score -1):

Store pointers to your large objects in STL containers.

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<LargeData>> largeObjects;
```

Comment: I know this method. But this 'length_error exception' does not occur in VisualC++2010&boost1.46 and Windows7. I'm using VC++2013&boost1.55 now.

Comment: I've decided to use pool-pointer method to avoid this problem and my application working well. Thanks all.